# How to catch unhandledRejection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a Telegram bot using [TelegrafJS](https://telegraf.js.org/#/), this framework wraps the `Telegram` API. The problem that I'm facing is how to correctly manage the `unhandled rejection`, in fact when I call this method:

```
await ctx.deleteMessage(message_id);
```

where `ctx` is the instance of `TelegrafJS` I got:

> Bot error: Error: 400: Bad Request: message to delete not found

this error happens 'cause the `message_id` that I passed no longer exists in `Telegram` chat. Now, the problem is that I have several controllers which can cause that problem.

I was looking at [Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch), my question is: can I set up a global `rejection handler` for my application, or should I use a `try/catch` block to methods potentially subject to exceptions?

Comment: You should wrap that code in a try/catch block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, and it is pretty simple:

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
    //handle it!
});
```

You can also catch the unhandled exceptions, using the same code basically:

```js
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    //handle it!
});
```

Comment: Is there a specific place where I should write your code? I actually added it in the entry point file and the `console.log` doesn't show anything

Comment: Yes, it must live in your entry point... They must always run before your code initializes. To this handle runs, you must not handle the rejections at any point in the feature you ran.

Comment: I added both lines before anything else, unfortunately when the exception is raised nothing is displayed

Comment: Bot error: Error: 400: Bad Request: message to delete not found

Comment: Yes... that is not an unhandled promise rejection... That handle would work if your code was throwing an error like this:
`(node:4796) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (r                                                                                                     ejection id: 1): Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
[1] (node:4796) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.
In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.
js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: I guess that what you want would be some sort of **express middleware** that handle errors raised by the request

Comment: I don't use `Express` 'cause I don't really need it, `TelegrafJS` is actually based on the `Composer` action triggered by Telegram API, I don't see yet how can I handle this

Comment: Ok, that is why I said "a sort of". Well... with try/catch blocks you are able to handle them?

Comment: yes I'm able to do so, I asked here to know if there is "a sort of" of practice to handle rejection

Answer (score 0):

test this code:

```
bot.use((ctx, next) => {
   try {
       ...
   } catch(error) {
       next();
   }
})
```

For error handler, you can use:

```
 bot.catch((err, ctx) => {
          console.log(err);
          return ctx.reply("Error Message");
    });
```